# Wordpress: how to remove characters from custom field when displayed

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

I've got a custom field for my client's site to display a custom tag.

Content in the custom field can be:
modern-art
abstract-art
artist

To template code to display the tag is:

```
<a href="http://site.com/tag/<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'hp-custom-tag', true) ?>"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'hp-custom-tag', true) ?></a>
```

Of course, I don't want to display the dash between modern-art. How can I remove the dash character using PHP or JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP [`str_rplace()`](http://php.net/str_replace)

```
echo str_replace('-', ' ', get_post_meta($post->ID, 'hp-custom-tag', true));
```

Comment: No problem!  Just remember that if you're going to try anything more complicated than a basic character swap, you should start researching regular expressions and `preg_match`